# How create a delay time in routing in angular 4?

Tags: time, delay, router

I have a form that in this form create a new job. Behind a register job button in this form, I have a router link that rote to detail of new job that was created.

When clicking on this button, Router Link does not have an id of this job because the job's id does not set. After clicking on the register job button then the job's id is set.

How delay in router link until id of the job is set?

Comment: can you please add code?

Comment: From my perspective you don't need to delay, to understand your question more  please set an example in https://stackblitz.com website

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Promises

```
addJobToList(job): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //
    // Create job here;
    //
    resolve(job.id);
    });
}

// <button (click)="createJob(formdata)" />

createJob(job): void {
    this.addJobToList(job).then(jobid => {
    this.router.navigate([`/jobdetails/${jobid}`]);
    });
}
```

more info: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/